# newline characters in json string don't appear in js object

Tags: javascript, json

I am building an app with React.

I am turning a json object into a js object using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).get(). The json contains a string `"First line \n Second line"`. When I turn it into a js object, the string becomes `"First line ↵ Second line"`. This does not get interpreted as a new line in a Chrome/Firefox browser.

How do I successfully interpret  `\n` as a new line?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I am using Redux-Promise to follow-up on the promise that axios returns.

Comment: Does the json string sent by the server contain an actual newline character or a backslash followed by the letter 'n'? `JSON.parse` seems to require the latter.

Comment: You could try adding `white-space: pre-line;` to your css for that element

Comment: @Traktor53 the json does indeed contain  a backslash followed by the letter 'n'. I am not using JSON.parse. Instead, I am using Redux-Promise to follow-up on the promise that axios returns.

Comment: @xkcd149 I tried this; unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: The brute force and ignorance method would be to change the down curve arrows back to newlines using, say, `newlineString = badString.replace( /\u21b5/g ,"\n");` Finding out where the substitution is occurring would require some debugging of library code. I would suggest starting with line 233 of uncompressed `axion.js` (where `JSON.parse` is called), but I don't have the setup to look into it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I am not sure where to put this code.  I tried line 233 of axios.js, but it didn't change anything. (That said I couldn't get a successful console.log from the file, so not sure I was doing it right.) To solve the issue, I ended up separating the string into an array of strings. This also gave me more flexibility on displaying the text, so a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your \n with another backslash. 
Try "First line \\n Second line"

Comment: I changed the JSON to "First line \\n Second line"; now I get "First line \n Second line" appearing in the browser. Not quite. The '\n' is still not correctly interpreted.

Comment: You could map over your text and insert break line - <br/> tags.

`{this.props.yourObject.string.split(“\n”).map(function(text) {
  return (
    <span>
      {text}
      <br/>
    </span>
  )
})}`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, however it would be really tedious as I have several strings with this problem and the solution is too verbose to be scalable.

Comment: Ok, valid point, two last suggestions. You could try replacing the \\n with Html-Entities.
&#10; for Line Feed and &#13; for a Carriage Return.
So replacing your \\n with "&#13;&#10;" could work.

Or, I recently had problems with react escaping Unicode chars.
Using String.fromCharCode(..) fixed this problem. So this could also work.
var newline = String.fromCharCode(13, 10);
text.replaceAll('\\n', newline);

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I tried to implement the  "&#13;&#10;"  but it didn't work. For the second suggestion, I am not sure where to put this code. To solve the issue, I ended up separating the string into an array of strings. This also gave me more flexibility on displaying the text, so a good compromise.